# Google Sheets - Grab data from a separate sheet and add it to a master sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that has a main master sheet, with a column for users to fill in their Name to show they are "working" on that row, then that row gets populated to their own tab based on a `=QUERY(Master!A3:AA,"select * Where L='Name'")` for each of the users' tabs, there is 8 total tabs where users are updating information. This is already quite a bit of processing on Googles part, so I am trying to generate a separate Google Sheet that pulls in the information that the users are entering on each of their tabs so the management can monitor that sheet for updates and then both sheets will run a lot faster/smoother.

I have tried using a VLookup with this syntax: `=vlookup(A3,importrange("sheetID",{"Name1!$A$3:$N";"Name2!$A$3:$N";"Name3!$A$3:$N";"Name4!$A$3:$N";"Name5!$A$3:$N";"Name6!$A$3:$N";"Name7!$A$3:$N";"Name8!$A$3:$N"}),12,FALSE)` which gives me an #N/A Error, cannot find Value '1' in VLOOKUP evaluation.

I have also tried using a `=QUERY({importrange("sheetID"x8 with the ranges)}, "Select Col12,Col13,Col14 where Col2 matches '^.\*($" &B3 & ").\*$'")`

That only returns headers, I am trying to get the query to basically find the unique key in Column A then spit out what is in Col 12-14, but that doesn't seem to work either. Columns 1-11 are static, but Columns 12-14 are what I am trying to populate for the management, which is the work that the staff is inputting on each of their tabs.

I can get the query working if I keep it on the same worksheet as the one the staff is working on, but then it bogs down the whole sheet so I would like to keep it separate if possible. Any ideas? I can't provide a sample sheet at this time since it has financial info on it, but I can add more details if I know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

your formula should be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3, {
 IMPORTRANGE("sheetID1", "Name1!A3:N");
 IMPORTRANGE("sheetID2", "Name2!A3:N");
 IMPORTRANGE("sheetID3", "Name3!A3:N");
 IMPORTRANGE("sheetID4", "Name4!A3:N");
 IMPORTRANGE("sheetID5", "Name5!A3:N");
 IMPORTRANGE("sheetID6", "Name6!A3:N");
 IMPORTRANGE("sheetID7", "Name7!A3:N");
 IMPORTRANGE("sheetID8", "Name8!A3:N")}, 12, 0)
```

keep in mind that every importrange needs to be run as a standalone formula where you connect your sheets by allowing access. only then you can use the above formula

Comment: Ok, I tried this out, but it's giving me #VALUE! Error "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows. Could this be because the sheets I'm trying to pull from are populated via the query WHERE formula?

Comment: @T-And ARRAY_LITERAL is on 99% a result of one of your importranges not being connected to your sheet. see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131436/186471